# Random Forest vs Neural Networks

Tags: machine-learning, neural-network, classification, random-forest

Why neural network is considered a better model than random forest in a classification task ?
I've tried both the models in a 10 class classification problem and the random forest perform better than a neural network with 1 hidden layer and only slightly worst than a neural network with 3 hidden layers. To compare them i used the same number of estimators (in the random forest) and neurons (for hidden layer in the neural network).

Comment: First, who considers neural networks to be better models than random forests? It will help us answer your questions if you say where you learned or read this. (I don’t dispute the sentiment, but it’ll help to know the source.) Second, you see for yourself that the neural net did better than the random forest, so that’s why a neural net might be preferable to a less accurate model.

Answer (score 2):

The performance of the machine learning models significantly depends on the type of data that you are using. Also, it is required to use a [statistical test](https://medium.com/analytics-vidhya/using-the-corrected-paired-students-t-test-for-comparing-the-performance-of-machine-learning-dc6529eaa97f) to compare the performance of two models given the data used for training and testing. I want to say that it might be misleading to say that one machine learning model performs better than the other.

In some cases, random forest model might perform well but not for all cases. That is also true about the neural networks. In case that the data is not complicated, random forest and tree-based models might outperform neural networks. However, this is not always the case especially when the data size is very large, neural networks are very useful because we can use very deep neural networks without any concerns regarding overfitting.